# Show that the outer measure $m^\ast$ of the rationals is zero e.g $m^\ast(\mathbb{Q})=0.$

Tags: measure-theory, solution-verification

> Show that the outer measure $m^\ast$ of the rationals is zero e.g $m^\ast(\mathbb{Q})=0.$

Since the rationals are countable we can represent them as $$\mathbb{Q}=\{q_j : j \in \mathbb{N}\}.$$

Now let $I_j = (q_j -\frac{\varepsilon}{2^j},q_j +\frac{\varepsilon}{2^j})$ denote the interval consisting the $j$:th rational number. Now the outer measure is defined as $$m^\ast(\mathbb{Q})= \inf\{\sum_{j=1}^\infty \ell(I_j) : \mathbb{Q} \subset \cup_{j=1}^\infty I_j\}.$$

Summing the intervals one has that $$\sum_{j=1}^\infty \ell(I_j)= 2\varepsilon \sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-j} = 2\varepsilon.$$

Now I'm wondering is it true that $$m^\ast(\mathbb{Q}) \le \sum_{j=1}^\infty \ell(I_j)= 2\varepsilon \sum_{j=1}^\infty 2^{-j} = 2\varepsilon?$$ If this was the case then clearly $m^\ast(\mathbb{Q}) =0$, but I'm not sure if this holds?

Comment: Where exactly do You doubt? The infimum is taken over all countable families of open intervals such that $\mathbb{Q}\subset\bigcup_{j=1}^ {\infty}I_j$ and You found for $\varepsilon >0$ arbitrary such a family where $\sum_{j=1}^{\infty}\ell (I_j)=2\varepsilon$

Comment: Yes it is true, by the definition of $m^*$ (you have a covering of the rationals by intervals whose lengths add up to something less than $2\varepsilon$)Now, as $m^*(\mathbb{Q})\leq 2\varepsilon$ for all $\varepsilon>0$, it follows $m^*(\mathbb{Q})=0$.